# Rspec testing validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am new to rails and I'm trying to understand testing using Rspec. I created a simple model (just for testing purposes) named Contact that contains firstname:string, lastname:string and email:string. I am just trying to set a test for firstname to fail if is empty.

my Rspec test is as follow:

```
describe Contact do
    it "creates a valid model" do
         contact = Contact.new(
            firstname: 'firstname',
            lastname: 'lastname',
            email: 'email'
            )
        expect(contact).to be_valid 
    end

 it "is invalid without a firstname" do
         contact = Contact.new(firstname: nil)
         contact.valid?
        expect(contact.errors[:firstname]).to include("can't be blank")
     end
```

My understanding is that this test should not return any failures but it does. Output below:

```
Failures:

  1) Contact is invalid without a firstname
     Failure/Error: expect(contact.errors[:firstname]).to include("can't be blank")
       expected [] to include "can't be blank"
     # ./spec/models/contact_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.11659 seconds (files took 2.39 seconds to load)
18 examples, 1 failure, 15 pending

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/contact_spec.rb:13 # Contact is invalid without a firstname
```

If I change the expect statement from ".to" to "not_to"  the test passes, so I think I am getting this backwards, any help or explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the validation in your model? Show your model code if so (if not, that's why there's no error).

Comment: I focused so much on setting Rspec and the test that i forgot to include the validation in my model, thank you so much.

Comment: Please mark your own answer as correct so that the question is closed.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't take this personally, but I'm voting to close your question because it was a simple oversight that isn't really going to help anyone else on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As smathy said in the comments, I forgot to include the validation inside my model. That solved my problem.